# new page character for ascii file?

Tags: printing

I need to print some docs, for example :

```
ABC
DEF

XYZ
AXA
```

I want to insert new page character between "DEF" and "XYZ" so that the printer starts a new page from "XYZ".

What character can do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, the ASCII character for new page (NP) was Control-L, or 012 (decimal). I have no idea if modern printers pay any attention to that sort of thing.